# Azure Yaml pipeline convert yaml to json

Tags: powershell, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have the below code which is supposed to comvert a yaml contract into json.  I am using powershell to do the conversion which works fine when I run it from powershell ISE on my PC.

However when I run it from a yaml pipeline I get an error regarding the json file "cannot find part of path".  When I add empty json file to my project it then runs but does not convert the yaml into json.  I'm not sure what I'm missing and I'm hoping somebody can help.  When I run the powershell script from powershell ISE I dont have to create the json file, it gets created if it does not exist, but from the pipeline it seems the json file has already exist or else it gives me that 'cannot find part of path' error

**powershell script:**

```
param(
  [string]$InputFile,
  [string]$OutputFile
)

$yaml = Get-Content $InputFile | ConvertFrom-Yaml
$json = $yaml | ConvertTo-Json
Set-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value $json
```

yaml code:

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Convert yaml to json
    inputs:
      targetType: 'filePath'
      filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_scripts/_powershell/convert-yaml-to-json.ps1
      arguments: >
        -InputFile = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test/input/myYaml.yaml" | ConvertFrom-Yaml
        -OutputFile = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test/output/MyJson.json"

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: "Publish converted JSON"
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_scripts/_yamlContract/output/myJson.json'
      ArtifactName: DFXMainJSON
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to convert a YAML file to JSON and publish the JSON file as a build artifact. I've adjusted your pipeline to execute `_scripts/_powershell/convert-yaml-to-json.ps1` on `test/input/myYaml.yaml` (file paths relative to the repository root), write to the artifacts staging directory, and publish that file.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Convert yaml to json
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    targetType: 'filePath'
    filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_scripts/_powershell/convert-yaml-to-json.ps1'
    arguments: >
      -InputFile "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test/input/myYaml.yaml"
      -OutputFile "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/myJson.json"

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: "Publish converted JSON"
  inputs:
    PublishBuildArtifacts: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/myJson.json'
    ArtifactName: DFXMainJSON
```

Microsoft docs: [System Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, however I now get this error:

Cannot find path 'C:\Agent\_work\133\s\=' because it does not exist.

I've not used Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory before, is there something I need to do before I can reference that variable?

Comment: `C:\Agent_work\133\s` makes sense for the value of `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`, but that `=` makes me wonder if the `arguments` value in the YAML got updated? You just want `-<ParameterName> Value` when providing argument values to a PowerShell script, no `=`.